# Passing a value through hyperlink in JSP page

Tags: html, jsp

I have a very simple JSP page first.jsp that gives reference to so many other JSP pages through hyperlink.

I am trying to pass a value through the hyperlink in first.jsp and retrieve it in second.jsp using request.getparameter().

I used:

```
<a href="second.jsp?value=1">Second JSP</a>
```

and in the second.jsp page I used:

```
alert( "value = " + <%= request.getParameter("value") %>);
```

but when I try to run the code and click on Second **JSP** I get a 404 page not found error for:**`second.jsp?value=1`**

Comment: can you post your second jsp's folder in your project.

Comment: both first and second are in the same folder.

Comment: javascript is not the approach.

Comment: Check the link address of your Second JSP link the server might have added some other folders in the path.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your URL to second JSP might not be good. "second.jsp" is not visible to your web app server the way you specified.

To fix this:

- If your jsps are resolved through a web app try:

`<a href="<webapp name>/second.jsp?value=1">Second JSP</a>`

- if you have `jsp` or similar directory that is visible outside of web app context do something like:

`<a href="jsp/second.jsp?value=1">Second JSP</a>`

Comment: Hi.. i tried.. Without the parameter ie "<a href = "second.jsp">" works just fine. But when i try to pass a value it doesnt.

Comment: It is bit of a reaching but try maybe:  <c:url value="second.jsp" var="theUrl">  
  <c:param name="value" value="1" />  
</c:url>  
<a href="${theUrl}"></a> and see what you get.

Answer (score -1):

Try `getQueryString()` method to access the value that you passed through the URL.

Then use string methods to extract the value form the URL.

For example, you pass the parameter as you mentioned

Use `getQueryString()` method in `second.jsp`, it will return the string `value = 1` as the result.

Comment: I don't see how using `getQueryString` in `second.jsp` will solve the `404 Not Found` error that the question is asking about.

Answer (score -2):

```
Html:

<a href="birth1.jsp?key=14APR010315381">
<center>
<font size="2" color="black">MIKE LOBO</font></center>
</a>

Jsp:
request.getParameter("key");
```

I m using in my project and its working fine